# Collection.sort strange error with sort

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

im trying to make sort by date from early to old. But i have strange bug/error// i dont know how explaine. Im using object models. Here code for sort

```
Collections.sort(models, new Comparator<Model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Model item1, Model item2) {
                int s1 = (int) item1.getUpdateAt();
                int s2 = (int) item2.getUpdateAt();
                return (s2 - s1);
            }
        });
```

and its info how its sort :

```
model: tyuiop time: 1484473575000
model: 0 time: 1516887006000
model: 1 time: 1516886848000
model: 2 time: 1516886840000
model: 3 time: 1516886833000
model: 4 time: 1516886825000
model: 5 time: 1516886818000
model: vhvyvtct time: 1516886592000
```

as we see from 0 to "vhvyvtctc " everything fine but "tyuiop" in wrong place. I cant understand why.  Can any help me to fix this ... error ? Please

**UPD** Omg  im idiot. Realy integer and long. Stupid my head. Thank guys
changing code to this style :

```
 Collections.sort(models, new Comparator<Model>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Model item1, Model item2) {
                    long s1 = item1.getUpdateAt();
                    long s2 = item2.getUpdateAt();
                    return Long.compare(s2, s1);
                }
            });
```

And its work perfect. Thank guys.

Comment: What type of data does `getUpdateAt()` return?

Comment: If `getUpdateAt()` returns the `millis` and you compare them as `Integers`, that's the problem. Go for `Long` instead (since `maxInt < currentTimeMillis`).

Comment: And preferably use Long.compare(value1, value2) //or in different order depending on wanted results; to avoid integer overflow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make things complicated use Long class's compare method

```
 Collections.sort(models, new Comparator<Model>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Model item1, Model item2) {
        return Long.compare(item1.getUpdateAt(), item2.getUpdateAt());
    }
});
```

Comment: Starting from Java 8 we can also rewrite this as  `models.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(Model::getUpdateAt).reversed())` (assuming `models` is a list, also added `.reversed()` based on OP code).

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code with some debug info, you can see that the long values can not be interpreted as int values correctly:

```
List<Long> longList = Arrays.asList(1516887006000L, 1516886848000L, 1516886840000L, 1516886833000L, 1516886825000L, 1516886818000L,
        1516886592000L, 1484473575000L);
Collections.sort(longList, (o1, o2) -> {
    System.out.println("Comparing: " + o1.intValue() + " with " + o2.intValue());
    return (o2.intValue() - o1.intValue());
});
```

Output:

> Comparing: 763392512 with 763550512
>   Comparing: 763384512 with 763392512
>   Comparing: 763377512 with 763384512
>   Comparing: 763369512 with 763377512
>   Comparing: 763362512 with 763369512
>   Comparing: 763136512 with 763362512
>   Comparing: -1585109416 with 763136512
>   Comparing: -1585109416 with 763377512
>   Comparing: -1585109416 with 763392512
>   Comparing: -1585109416 with 763550512

You can see the values are not correct. So better will be to use the comparison of Long:

```
Collections.sort(models, (o1, o2) -> {
    return o1.getUpdateAt().compareTo(o2.getUpdateAt());
});
```